# PHP: HTML special characters wrongly formatted in string (UTF8)

Tags: php, utf-8

I have a CURL script that extract the data from a normal JSON feed. The feed return html code but the special html characters are wrongly formated.

For example, I get the following string:

â˜… Beautiful new graphics
â˜… Gorgeous new organic environments
â˜… New obstacles

The data is stored into a DB and I want to store the special html characters as well.

How can I preserve the special html characters. My script is as follow:

```
$curl_session = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_URL,'https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=572395608');
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,10); 
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);                
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$source = curl_exec($curl_session);

$source_decoded = json_decode($source, true);

print_r($source_decoded);
exit;
```

Comment: What does `mb_detect_encoding($source));` return?

Comment: @mkaatman: it return: UTF-8. Using utf8_decode(), I get this as an output: ? Beautiful new graphics ? Gorgeous new organic environments ? New obstacles

Comment: How about: `echo htmlspecialchars($source, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');`

Comment: @mkaatman: It is still wrongly formatted: \nâ˜… Beautiful new graphics\nâ˜… Gorgeous new organic environments\nâ˜… New obstacles

Comment: I'm setting it up locally to try it. One moment.

Comment: @mkaatman: Thanks! The special characters are found in the "description".

Comment: http://kunststube.net/frontback

Comment: This is working for me: http://pastebin.com/n4VaMDzC I see the stars.

Comment: @mkaatman: It seems to me working in some browser now. It's not working on Internet Explorer but it's working on Chrome. How weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are receiving the characters as UTF-8, because this is the only encoding allowed and possible in JSON.

But you output them NOT as UTF-8. Change this. Send a content type header that tells the client which encoding has been used. Or convert the characters to an encoding you are using, and risk loosing those characters that cannot be encoded with it.

Comment: In short, use: header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');